# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickDrawException' with message 'Unable to set fill pattern URL'

Tags: php, imagick

I'm using Imagick to create image but it has an error:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickDrawException' with message 'Unable to set fill pattern URL'

**This is my code:**

$im = new Imagick();

$im->newPseudoImage(50, 50, "gradient:red-black");

$im->setImageFormat("png");

$draw = new ImagickDraw();

$draw->pushPattern('gradient', 0, 0, 50, 50);

$draw->composite(Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0, 50, 50, $im);

$draw->popPattern();

$draw->setFillPatternURL('#gradient');

$draw->setFontSize(52);

$draw->annotation(20, 50, "Hello World!");

$canvas = new Imagick();

$canvas->newImage(350, 70, "white");

$canvas->drawImage($draw);

$canvas->borderImage('black', 1, 1);

$canvas->setImageFormat('png');

header("Content-Type: image/png");

echo $canvas;

Comment: you need more exception message, where occurred, what method occuurred.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
$draw->popPattern();
$draw->setFillPatternURL('#gradient');
```

to

```
$draw->setFillPatternURL('#gradient');
$draw->popPattern();
```

use your pattern, before it terminated.

Comment: Thanks, i tried your solution, and another error appeared: 'URLNotFound `#gradient`'